# How to stop jzy3d from printing a help message?

Tags: java, jzy3d

When using `AnalysisLauncher.open(new AbstractAnalysisObj)`, the library always prints the following message:

```
Rotate     : Left click and drag mouse
Scale      : Roll mouse wheel
Z Shift    : Right click and drag mouse
Animate    : Double left click
Screenshot : Press 's'

------------------------------------
```

This is pretty irritating especially when I need multiple plots, the message is just printed over and over again. How can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `ChartLauncher.openChart(...)` instead. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-api/src/api/org/jzy3d/analysis/AnalysisLauncher.java) of `AnalysisLauncher` it's easy to see how this is accomplished.